# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`product`' given input columns: [jsontostructs(message)];

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

```
    C:\Users\sorun\.jdks\openjdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:D:\Intellij IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=50945:D:\Intellij IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\sorun\IdeaProjects\spark-streaming-kafka\target\classes;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-sql_2.11\2.2.0\spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\univocity\univocity-parsers\2.2.1\univocity-parsers-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-sketch_2.11\2.2.0\spark-sketch_2.11-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.11\2.2.0\spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro\1.7.7\avro-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\paranamer\paranamer\2.3\paranamer-2.3.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.4.1\commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\tukaani\xz\1.0\xz-1.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-mapred\1.7.7\avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill_2.11\0.8.0\chill_2.11-0.8.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\kryo-shaded\3.0.3\kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\minlog\1.3.0\minlog-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.1\objenesis-2.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill-java\0.8.0\chill-java-0.8.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-client\2.6.5\hadoop-client-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-common\2.6.5\hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.2\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\xmlenc\xmlenc\0.52\xmlenc-0.52.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.6\commons-configuration-1.6.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.7.0\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils-core\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.5.0\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-auth\2.6.5\hadoop-auth-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\directory\server\apacheds-kerberos-codec\2.0.0-M15\apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\directory\server\apacheds-i18n\2.0.0-M15\apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\directory\api\api-asn1-api\1.0.0-M20\api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\directory\api\api-util\1.0.0-M20\api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-client\2.6.0\curator-client-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\htrace\htrace-core\3.0.4\htrace-core-3.0.4.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs\2.6.5\hadoop-hdfs-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-util\6.1.26\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.9.1\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.3.04\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app\2.6.5\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common\2.6.5\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-client\2.6.5\hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-server-common\2.6.5\hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle\2.6.5\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-api\2.6.5\hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core\2.6.5\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-common\2.6.5\hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.2\jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\javax\xml\stream\stax-api\1.0-2\stax-api-1.0-2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-jaxrs\1.9.13\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-xc\1.9.13\jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient\2.6.5\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-annotations\2.6.5\hadoop-annotations-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-launcher_2.11\2.2.0\spark-launcher_2.11-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-common_2.11\2.2.0\spark-network-common_2.11-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\fusesource\leveldbjni\leveldbjni-all\1.8\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-shuffle_2.11\2.2.0\spark-network-shuffle_2.11-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-unsafe_2.11\2.2.0\spark-unsafe_2.11-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jets3t\jets3t\0.9.3\jets3t-0.9.3.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.3\httpcore-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.6\httpclient-4.3.6.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1.1\activation-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\mx4j\mx4j\3.0.2\mx4j-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4.7\mail-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.51\bcprov-jdk15on-1.51.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\jamesmurty\utils\java-xmlbuilder\1.0\java-xmlbuilder-1.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\net\iharder\base64\2.3.8\base64-2.3.8.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-recipes\2.6.0\curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-framework\2.6.0\curator-framework-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\zookeeper\zookeeper\3.4.6\zookeeper-3.4.6.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\16.0.1\guava-16.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math3\3.4.1\commons-math3-3.4.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.16\slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.16\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.16\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.16\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\ning\compress-lzf\1.0.3\compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.1.2.6\snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\net\jpountz\lz4\lz4\1.3.0\lz4-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\roaringbitmap\RoaringBitmap\0.5.11\RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\2.2\commons-net-2.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.11.8\scala-library-2.11.8.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-jackson_2.11\3.2.11\json4s-jackson_2.11-3.2.11.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-core_2.11\3.2.11\json4s-core_2.11-3.2.11.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-ast_2.11\3.2.11\json4s-ast_2.11-3.2.11.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scalap\2.11.0\scalap-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.11.0\scala-compiler-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\modules\scala-xml_2.11\1.0.1\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\modules\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\1.0.1\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-client\2.22.2\jersey-client-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0.1\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-api\2.4.0-b34\hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-utils\2.4.0-b34\hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\aopalliance-repackaged\2.4.0-b34\aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\javax.inject\2.4.0-b34\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-locator\2.4.0-b34\hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-common\2.22.2\jersey-common-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\bundles\repackaged\jersey-guava\2.22.2\jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\osgi-resource-locator\1.0.1\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-server\2.22.2\jersey-server-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-jaxb\2.22.2\jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\containers\jersey-container-servlet\2.22.2\jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\containers\jersey-container-servlet-core\2.22.2\jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.43.Final\netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.9.9.Final\netty-3.9.9.Final.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\clearspring\analytics\stream\2.7.0\stream-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-core\3.1.2\metrics-core-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-jvm\3.1.2\metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-json\3.1.2\metrics-json-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-graphite\3.1.2\metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-scala_2.11\2.6.5\jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-paranamer\2.6.5\jackson-module-paranamer-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\ivy\ivy\2.4.0\ivy-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\oro\oro\2.0.8\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\net\razorvine\pyrolite\4.13\pyrolite-4.13.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\net\sf\py4j\py4j\0.10.4\py4j-0.10.4.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-crypto\1.0.0\commons-crypto-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-catalyst_2.11\2.2.0\spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.11.8\scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\janino\janino\3.0.0\janino-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\janino\commons-compiler\3.0.0\commons-compiler-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.5.3\antlr4-runtime-4.5.3.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-tags_2.11\2.2.0\spark-tags_2.11-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-column\1.8.2\parquet-column-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-common\1.8.2\parquet-common-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-encoding\1.8.2\parquet-encoding-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-hadoop\1.8.2\parquet-hadoop-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-format\2.3.1\parquet-format-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-jackson\1.8.2\parquet-jackson-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.11\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.11\jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.6.5\jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.6.0\jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.6.5\jackson-core-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\xbean\xbean-asm5-shaded\4.4\xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\spark-project\spark\unused\1.0.0\unused-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11\2.2.0\spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\org\apache\kafka\kafka-clients\0.10.0.1\kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sorun\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.3\gson-2.8.3.jar StreamingConsumer

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/06/19 12:39:42 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/C:/Users/sorun/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.6.5/hadoop-auth-2.6.5.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
20/06/19 12:39:43 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/06/19 12:39:44 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Streaming-kafka
20/06/19 12:39:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: OZAN-OKAN
20/06/19 12:39:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: OZAN-OKAN
20/06/19 12:39:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
20/06/19 12:39:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
20/06/19 12:39:44 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(OZAN-OKAN); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(OZAN-OKAN); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/06/19 12:39:45 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 50966.
20/06/19 12:39:45 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/06/19 12:39:45 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
20/06/19 12:39:45 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
20/06/19 12:39:45 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
20/06/19 12:39:45 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\sorun\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-0794380e-6e2b-4559-bf6c-7d10c2074bc8
20/06/19 12:39:45 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 1040.4 MB
20/06/19 12:39:45 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/06/19 12:39:45 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.56.1:4040
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 50975.
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.56.1:50975
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 50975, None)
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.56.1:50975 with 1040.4 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 50975, None)
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 50975, None)
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 50975, None)
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/C:/Users/sorun/IdeaProjects/spark-streaming-kafka/spark-warehouse/').
20/06/19 12:39:46 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/C:/Users/sorun/IdeaProjects/spark-streaming-kafka/spark-warehouse/'.
20/06/19 12:39:47 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
20/06/19 12:39:47 INFO CatalystSqlParser: Parsing command: string
20/06/19 12:39:49 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: CAST(value AS STRING) message
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`product`' given input columns: [jsontostructs(message)];
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(TreeNode.scala:323)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterator$3.apply(MapLike.scala:246)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterator$3.apply(MapLike.scala:246)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.foreach(IterableLike.scala:311)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike$class.force(TraversableViewLike.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.force(IterableLike.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$6.apply(QueryPlan.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.resolveAndBind(ExpressionEncoder.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.as(Dataset.scala:380)
    at StreamingConsumer.main(StreamingConsumer.java:24)
20/06/19 12:39:50 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
20/06/19 12:39:50 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.56.1:4040
20/06/19 12:39:50 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
20/06/19 12:39:50 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
20/06/19 12:39:50 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
20/06/19 12:39:50 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
20/06/19 12:39:50 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
20/06/19 12:39:50 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
20/06/19 12:39:50 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/06/19 12:39:50 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\sorun\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-b70ecbcc-e6cf-4328-9069-97cc41cc72d7

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anlif.png)

Comment: Please reformat everything. Use triple ` to format the multiline code. Here is more https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
cannot resolve '`product`' given input columns: [jsontostructs(message)];
```

Above exception message says the column which you are selecting is not available in `DataFrame`, rename the column `jsontostructs(message)` to `product` & use this column in `select`.

Comment: CAN YOU SAY WHAT TO CHANGE BY LOOKING AT THE **CODE** I ADD UNDER THE ERROR?. I just started the software, so I haven't grasped it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Change `schema).as("json"))`

```
Dataset<SearchProductModel> data = load.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as message")
                .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("message"), schema).as("json"))
                .select("json.*")
                .as(Encoders.bean(SearchProductModel.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you have "message" field in your model,
add it to schema struct type

```
StructType schema = new StructType().add("product","string").add("time", DataTypes.TimestampType).add("message", DataTypes.StringType);
```